# Markup text inside second volta bracket

Tags: lilypond, repeats

I want to format text in the headings of both 1st and 2nd ending Volta brackets in Lilypond.  There are several examples of formatted text in the first ending bracket, but I cannot seem to find one with formatted text (using a markup command) in the second ending bracket.

In other words, I have this snippet:

```
01     voltaAdLib = \markup { 1. 2. 3... \text \italic { ad lib. } }
02
03     \relative c'' {
04       c1
05       \set Score.repeatCommands = #(list (list 'volta voltaAdLib) 'start-repeat)
06       c4 b d e
07       \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta #f) (volta "4.") end-repeat)
08       f1
09       \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta #f))
10     }
```

And I want to add another `myText = \markup...` block in place of "4." in line 07.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

That's more a question of Scheme syntax than of LilyPond.  First you have to note that `'` in Scheme is used for quoting material rather than having it interpreted.  What's worth quoting are lists (the things included in `(`...`)`) and symbols (basic strings used like identifiers).  A list, when quoted, has all of its elements quoted and then is a list.  If it is unquoted, it is evaluated.  An evaluated list is a function call, with the first element being the function and the remaining elements being the values, all of which are evaluated before the call.

A typical function is `list` which takes its arguments and puts them into a list.

Another item that is different when evaluated is a symbol (mentioned above).  Unevaluated, it is a unique thing that does not compare equal to any other unique thing.  Evaluated, it is more or less a variable access.

So in the above,

```
    #(list (list 'volta voltaAdLib) 'start-repeat)
```

is basically the same as

```
    #'((volta i-would-like-the-value-of-voltaAdLib) start-repeat)
```

for which one can use quasiquotes which quote anything that is not preceded by `,`.  So one could write this as

```
    #`((volta ,voltaAdLib) start-repeat)
```

Note that I am now using the backward-pointing quasi-quote after `#`.  If I used the regular quote, the result would be equivalent to

```
    #'((volta (unquote voltaAdLib)) start-repeat)
```

which does not help.  Quasiquotes are usually quite more convenient for list-building with only a few values from variables or function calls than building the list with explicit calls of list.  So getting back to your use-case, you'd likely want

```
    \set Score.repeatCommands = #`((volta #f) (volta ,#{ \markup "ad lib." #}) end-repeat)
```

Using `#{ \markup ... #}` directly in Scheme is supported since version 2.16 I think, but of course you can also use a variable like in your first example.