# Custom text in volta with Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving, repeats

I'm trying to put custom text in voltas when engraving with Lilypond. The problem is not adding text, but adding it with the formatting I want. I am aware that a similar question was asked and answered ([Markup text inside second volta bracket](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23654/markup-text-inside-second-volta-bracket)) but it doesn't answer my problem because the result is really ugly. It's what I already have, except the method is different; I tried it, so expect if I did something wrong, it's not what I want.

What I have for now looks like:
[image: score with custom text under volta brackets]

The idea is that the text in the voltas would rather look like the text I put under the B and the C in the first two measures.

My code for now is :

```
\version "2.20.0"

aaaa = _\markup { \italic \teeny "Suite" }

bbbb = \tweak DynamicText.self-alignment-X #LEFT
    #(make-dynamic-script 
        (markup
            #:with-dimensions '(0 . 5) '(0 . 0) #:line
            (#:normal-text #:italic #:teeny "Fin")))

pianoUpper = \relative c' {
    \override DynamicLineSpanner.staff-padding = #3
    \clef "treble"
    \key f \major

    bes1 \bbbb
    \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta "Suite"))
    c \aaaa
    \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta #f))
    \bar "||"
    \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta "Fin"))
    d
    \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta #f))
    \bar "||"
    e_"D.S. al Fine" 
    \bar "S-S"
    \break
}

pianoLower = \relative c {
    \clef "bass"
    \key f \major
    
}

\score {
    \new PianoStaff 
        <<
            \new Staff = "upper" {
                \pianoUpper
            }
            \new Staff = "lower" {
                \pianoLower
            }
        >>
}
```

How can I get formatting (italics) in the volta bracket text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work. Just don't put anything before `\text`. Modified
`\set Score.repeatCommands = #(list(list 'volta finVoltaTxt) 'end-repeat)` to same form as `\set Score.repeatCommands = #(list(list 'volta suiteVoltaTxt))` because the two variables `suiteVoltaTxt` and `finVoltaTxt` should really be together; not one done one way, the other done another way.

```
suiteVoltaTxt = \markup { \text \italic Suite}
finVoltaTxt = \markup { \text \italic Fin}

pianoUpper = \relative c' {
  \key f \major
  \time 4/4
   
   bes1
   \set Score.repeatCommands = #(list(list 'volta suiteVoltaTxt))
   c1 
   \set Score.repeatCommands = #(list(list 'volta finVoltaTxt) 'end-repeat)
   d1
   \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta #f))
   e |
  
}
```